# How to patch a floating environment so that the patched command floats

Tags: floats, marginpar, patching

I'm using `etoolbox` to patch some environments. I want to use `\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\marginpar{foo}}` to put something in the margin by the float. But the marginpar is typeset where the environment is written, not where the float is output, if you see what I mean. How can I get something to float with the table?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on Martin Scharrer's redefinition of the `table` environment and egreg's statement that insertions are forbidden inside insertions: This is a case where `\marginpar` doesn't work, but `\marginnote` (from the [marginnote](http://ctan.org/pkg/marginnote) package) does.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{marginnote}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{table}[1][]{\@float{table}[#1]\marginnote{foo}}{\end@float}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{table}
\centering
(Table content)
\caption{A table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice. Much better than my hack: `\llap{\raisebox{-\height}[0pt][0pt]{\parbox{\marginparwidth}{foo\\bar}}\hspace{\marginparsep}}%
    \vspace{-1ex}`

Comment: I guess this sort of redefinition might break if you load `booktabs` or similar? (Or does that only mess with tabular...)

Comment: It's probably easier for my purposes to patch `caption` rather than the float. But thanks for the `marginnote` tip¬

Answer (score 7):

You can't. Both tables and marginpars are insertions and it's forbidden to have an insertion inside an insertion.

If you try to put a `\marginpar` in a `table` environment you get

```
! LaTeX Error: Float(s) lost.
```

Martin's redefinition doesn't work either:

```
! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.
```

It wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: Yeah, yeah, always test your own code ... This reminds me on the footnote inside a footnote question which ironically got answered by Seamus. You could try to fake the marginpar by using `\rlap{\hspace{<large enough>}foo}` or similar.

Comment: OK. So you can't put a marginpar in a table. But can you (in general) get something to float with a float by patching some command?

Comment: @Seamus No, it's forbidden by TeX rules. TeXbook, p. 117

Comment: @egreg: couldn't you define the figure environment as something like `\savebox\FloatBox\vbox\bgroup` and `\egroup\TurnFloatBoxIntoAnInsertion`, allowing nested floating objects?

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch When then `\FloatBox` goes inside the `\insert`, the `\insert` inside it will become illegal. Only if you manage floats *without* `\insert` this becomes possible.

Comment: @egreg: I was thinking of saving the `\insert` inside it as a global box and add to `\TurnFloatBoxIntoAnInsert` some code that also turns the nested "inserts" into `\insert`. Not saying it's easy, but it seems possible. Also, do floats really need to be treated as inserts?

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch The problem would be to keep these inserts together. It's however not necessary to use `\insert` for floats; would you write the new output routine? :)

Comment: @egreg: I'm not sure whether Joseph, Frank, or me will write the OR for LaTeX3. We'll see then :).

Answer (score 1):

The AtBeginEnvironment code is executed just before the internal macro of the environment (`\table`) here:

```
$ latexdef -p etoolbox begin

\begin:
macro:#1->\csuse {@beforebegin@#1@hook}%
  \@ifundefined {#1}%
    {\def \reserved@a {\@latex@error {Environment #1 undefined}\@eha }}%
    {\def \reserved@a {\def \@currenvir {#1}\edef \@currenvline {\on@line }
     \csuse {@begin@#1@hook}\csname #1\endcsname }}%
  \@ignorefalse \begingroup \@endpefalse \reserved@a
```

The important part here is `\csuse {@begin@#1@hook}\csname #1\endcsname`.
So you can't use these hooks to do this.

Note that `table` is simply:

```
\table:
\long macro:->\@float {table}

\endtable:
\long macro:->\end@float
```

So I would write:

```
\renewenvironment{table}[1][]{\@float{table}[#1]\marginpar{foo}}{\end@float}
```

and insert the code manually. Of course you need to be careful if you load any packages which change the definition of `table`.